# Compare object values after typecasting

Tags: java, object, compare

I am passing a two values that needs to be compared as string format, but their actual types are different.

So, i call a typecast function which will typecast the given value and return an object.

```
public object typeCast(columnDataType,columnFormat,columnValue){

       case "(IntegerType)":
         return Integer.parseInt(filterValue);
       case "(LongType)":
         return Long.parseLong(filterValue);    
   }
```

However, I am not able to do "greater than" or "lesser than" operation.

```
a1>a2
```

> not defined for object types.

Comment: you do return an `Object`, what do you expect? How can one `Object` be greater than another one?

Answer (score 1):

Problem 1:  You cannot use `<` or `>` operators on reference types.  Possible solution: Use the `Comparable<T>.comparteTo(T)` method.

Problem 2:  The `Object` class does not implement `Comparable`.  Possible solution: Return a `Comparable<?>`.

Problem 3:  If you return a `Comparable<?>` you lose the benefits of generic type safety.  (Meh ....)

I think it would help if we could see more of the context.  And also *real* Java code which is (at least) syntactically valid, so that we don't have to guess ...

---

Incidentally, what you are doing (from the Java perspective) is not type casting.  It is actually *conversion* of values.  For reference types, the distinction between casting and converting is start.  Type casting gives you the same object as before: conversion gives you a different object.

Answer (score 0):

That happens, because the compiler doesn't know what is actually gonna happen in your case, how it's all gonna go (how it's suppose to know, when even you don't know that yet?).

Answer (score 0):

Before returning, you can cast parsed values to one common type (`long` or `double`, for example) and change method's returned type also.

Or use class `Number` and call `longValue()` or `doubleValue()` when comparing.